# Debug unwanted stop

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm facing a very annoying problem.
I'm finishing an Java SE (updated version) application, using Netbeans (7.3, 7.2) and sometimes, when the debugger is at this line, it stops.

```
javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
```

It stops with no errors. I mean, the debugger does not go to the next line, it simply stops at this line while the application is still running on the background.
This problem does not occur when I'm running the application in a regular way (using no debug).

Does anyone have any clue about this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Remove the breakpoint!

Comment: There is no breakpoint! That's the problem...

Comment: Does restarting NetBeans help?

Comment: I've tried to do it, but it did not help. Actually, I've tried to reinstall Netbeans, to install other versions of it, to reinstall Java, and none of these measures seem to solve the problem.